# How to mixin methods to underscore without introducing them globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, underscore.js

so you have a bunch of methods you have tacked on to underscore within your package:

```
_.mixin({
    foo: function() {},
    bar: function() {} //etc
});
```

but you don't want to risk conflicting with the main application or other packages, what's the best way to prevent that?

The 2 options I'm considering are adding a few underscores before my methods OR cloning underscore onto a different leading character, eg: U.foo, but when you clone it via:

```
U = _;
_.extend(U, _)
```

both U and _ get your methods when you now do:

```
U.mixin({
   foo: function() {}
});
```

Without adding additional code that will increase file size, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Create a single function which returns all the separate functions as props:

```js
_.mixin({
    ns:function(){
        return {
            baz:function(){
                document.write('baz');
            }
        }
    }
});
_.ns().baz();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Now all of your functions have their own namespace `ns`

Comment: Well that gets the job done! Nice job. Still rather find a way to just replace the lead character because this is quite verbose. Any ideas? Assign the return of baz to another var?

Comment: that doesn't actually work, you don't get access to any other underscore methods. And if you do, I'm wondering if chaining would even continue to work??